# SQLite find table row where a subset of columns satisfies a specified constraint

Tags: sqlite, constraints

I have the following SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE visits(urid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    hash TEXT,dX INTEGER,dY INTEGER,dZ INTEGER);
```

Typical content would be

```
# select * from visits;
  urid |  hash     |  dx   |   dY   |   dZ
 ------+-----------+-------+--------+------
   1   |  'abcd'   |  10   |   10   |   10  
   2   |  'abcd'   |  11   |   11   |   11
   3   |  'bcde'   |   7   |    7   |    7  
   4   |  'abcd'   |  13   |   13   |   13 
   5   |  'defg'   |  20   |   21   |   17
```

What I need to do here is identify the `urid` for the table row which satisfies the constraint

```
hash = 'abcd' AND (nearby >= (abs(dX - tX) + abs(dY - tY) + abs(dZ - tZ))
```

with the *smallest deviation* - in the sense of smallest sum of absolute distances

In the present instance with

```
 nearby = 7
 tX = tY = tZ = 12
```

there are three rows that meet the above constraint but with different deviations

```
  urid |  hash     |  dx   |   dY   |   dZ   |   deviation
 ------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------------
   1   |  'abcd'   |  10   |   10   |   10   |       6
   2   |  'abcd'   |  11   |   11   |   11   |       3
   4   |  'abcd'   |  12   |   12   |   12   |       3
```

in which case I would like to have reported `urid = 2` or `urid = 3` - I don't actually care which one gets reported.

Left to my own devices I would fetch the full set of matching rows and then dril down to the one that matches my secondary constraint - smallest deviation - in my own Java code.  However, I suspect that is not necessary and it can be done in SQL alone.  My knowledge of SQL is sadly too limited here.  I hope that someone here can put me on the right path.

---

I now have managed to do the following

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE h1(v1 INTEGER,v2 INTEGER);
SELECT urid,(SELECT (abs(dX - 12) + abs(dY - 12) + abs(dZ - 12))) devi FROM visits WHERE hash = 'abcd';
```

which gives

```
--SELECT * FROM h1 
  urid |  devi     |
-------+-----------+
   1   |    6      |
   2   |    3      |
   4   |    3      |
```

following which I issue

```
select urid from h1 order by v2 asc limit 1;
```

which yields urid = 2, the result I am after.  Whilst this works, I would like to know if there is a better/simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close! You have all of the components you need, you just have to put them together into a single query.

Consider:

```
SELECT urid
     , (abs(dx - :tx) + abs(dy - :tx) + abs(dz - :tx)) AS devi
FROM visits
WHERE hash=:hashval AND devi < :nearby
ORDER BY devi
LIMIT 1
```

Line by line, first you list the rows and computed values you want (`:tx` is a *placeholder*; in your code you want to *prepare* a statement and then *bind* values to the placeholders before *executing* the statement) from the visit table.

Then in the `WHERE` clause you restrict what rows get returned to those matching the particular `hash` (That column should have an *index* for best results... `CREATE INDEX visits_idx_hash ON visits(hash)` for example), and that have a `devi` that is less than the value of the `:nearby` placeholder. (I think `devi < :nearby` is clearer than `:nearby >= devi`).

Then you say that you want those results sorted in increasing order according to `devi`, and `LIMIT` the returned results to a single row because you don't care about any others (If there are no rows that meet the WHERE constraints, nothing is returned).

Comment: Thanks.  You provide an answer and follow that up with a full explanation. +1!